# Generate private key Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm very new to Firebase, and I need a private key to access the Firebase Admin SDK for my backend. Actually, my company has been using Firebase for a long time, but no one knows where the private key is or if it has been generated.

[image]

Here are my questions:

1. What will happen to the old private key when I click "generate"? Can we still use it, or will the key become obsolete and cause some services to stop working?
2. Can the private key be used by multiple platforms simultaneously?

Thank you

Answer (score 38):

> 1. What will happen to the old private key when I click "generate"? Can we still use it, or will the key become obsolete and cause some services to stop working?

Your old private key is stored, so you can still use it if you decide to generate a new private key.

> 2. Can the private key be used by multiple platforms simultaneously?

Yes

You can use both keys at the same time for different purposes.

You can [manage your keys here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/).

Select your project and look under Key Id to find all the keys you have generated. You can also delete old or unused keys.

Comment: how can we get public key?